# How to set up SFML+CMake+Codeblocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml, cmake-gui

I am following a book called SFML blueprints.

although, it had tutorials on how to set up SFML, I later moved to official sfml tutorials given on https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-cb.php.
Then, I did the following things-:
1) Downloaded SFML source code, CMake, Codeblocks mingw(it works fine with c++)
2) Then I went to c-make gui
3) Put the       SFML folder and SFML/build folder there.
SUCCESS!
4) But, next I go to Code::blocks. Now some say that I need to build target, some say to Go to Project->Build Options->and change Compiler and Linker to include and lib path likewise; add debug and release to -sfml-d etc etc.
But neither of any ways worked. 
I am amazed!
what can I have missed here? What is the full process?
I have visited similar questions like that
[setting up sfml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056999/setting-up-sfml?rq=1)
There was a visual studio tut also
[Compiling SFML for Visual Studio 2012 using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793098/compiling-sfml-for-visual-studio-2012-using-cmake/23810154#23810154)
Not a stackoverflow answer-:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/103582/
Followed some reddit also, but nothing seems to work, I hope I can find my solution here!

Comment: Actually step 2) [build SFML yourself](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/compile-with-cmake.php), this will require to build ~8 other libraries

Comment: I have done that tutorial all except from Let's begin this section with some good news: you won't have to go through the configuration step any more, even if you update your working copy of SFML. CMake is smart: It adds a custom step to the generated makefiles/projects, that automatically regenerates the build files whenever something changes. 
You're now ready to build SFML. Of course, how to do it depends on what makefiles/projects you've generated. If you created a project/solution/workspace, open it with your IDE and build SFML like you would any other

Comment: feels like noone knows how to do this! thanks guys for your support!